# JSHint warning "Function declared within loop referencing an outer scope variable may lead to confusing semantics" . How can I improve the code?

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, jshint

JSHint shows the error:
"Function declared within loop referencing an outer scope variable may lead to confusing semantics".
How can I improve the following code to get rid of the warning?

```
var getPrecedence  = function getPrecedence(operator, operators) {
    var keys = Object.keys(Object(operators));
    for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        var check = Object.keys(operators[keys[i]]).some(function (item) {
            return item === operator;
    });
    if (check) return operators[keys[i]][operator];
    }
};
```

Comment: It would help us help you if you showed us an example of the structure of `operators`. Not least because `Object(operators)` looks quite odd looks quite odd...

Comment: This is operators.

Comment: this.operators = {"operators": {
          "^": 1,
          "*": 2,
          "/": 2,
          "%": 2,
          "+": 3,
          "-": 3,
        },
        "functions": {
          "log": 0,
          "sin": 0,
          "cos": 0,
          "tan": 0,
        },
        "brackets": {
          "open": ["("],
          "close": [")"]
        },
        "equal": {
          "=": 4
        }
      };

Comment: To improve the question, use the "edit" link under the question, not comments (particularly not when you need code formatting).

Comment: @Kasia You might want to change your data structure into having a single level only, like `{"^": {prec: 1, type: "op"}, "*": {prec: 2, type: "op"}, "log": {prec: 0, type:"fn"}, "(": {prec: 4, type:"open"}` or so. (Although your structure for the brackets doesn't seem to fit in there anyway)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are supposed not to use the function expression inside the loop body, but instead declare it outside:

```
function getPrecedence(operator, operators) {
    function isOperator(item) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return item === operator;
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(Object(operators));
    for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        var check = Object.keys(operators[keys[i]]).some(isOperator);
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
        if (check) return operators[keys[i]][operator];
    }
}
```

Of course the whole thing could be simplified by just using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `some`, and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of the loop:

```
function getPrecedence(operator, operators) {
    var keys = Object.keys(Object(operators));
    var opkey = keys.find(key =>
        Object.keys(operators[key]).includes(operator)
    );
    if (opkey) return operators[opkey][operator];
}
```

And finally, `Object.keys(…).includes(…)` can be simplified to `operator in operators[key]`.

Comment: *"And finally, `Object.keys(…).includes(…)` can be simplified to `operator in operators[key]`"* In **this** case, though not, of course, in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

*Add it before calling the function, this one will bypass that check*

```
/* jshint -W083 */
```